# What licence should I choose for my project?

Tags: licensing

I originally thought of creative commons when while reading a book about wordpress (professional wordpress), I learned that I should also specify that the product is provided

> ... WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
>   implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

and they recommend GNU GPL.  How do I write a license or select 1?

btw, what does `MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE` mean actually? Isn't without warranty enough?

Comment: It's better if you *don't* try to write a new license. Hire a Copyright attorney if you can't find an existing one you can use. Also realize that most licenses are written under US laws, where a little more specificity is often required in disclaimers.

Comment: Re. without warranty - generally in law if in any doubt you make it clear.  I'd imagine that this in response to a specific historic case where the straight disclaimer wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For small bits of code, I generally release them under the X11 licence. The problem with the GPL is that it's far too complicated for code that you don't really care enough about to protect. If you *really* don't want people using your code in commercial products, you would need to monitor for infringement and fight it out in court, which isn't really worth the time or the effort for small, free, open-source projects.

> Copyright (c)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
>    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
>    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>    all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
>    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
>    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
>    THE SOFTWARE.

**EDIT:** If the body of code is more substantial, and you feel that you've invested enough time in it that you would be willing to protect it, by all means use the GPL to protect it.

Comment: Although if you release code under the GPL, I suspect the commercial companies would be much more unwilling to steal it based on that its GPL'd.

Comment: I'm not convinced that it makes a big difference. The GPL is so complicated, that a lot of companies probably infringe all the time, secure in the knowledge that the "little guy" can never come after them. I reckon that for every infringement that the FSF catches, there are probably tons that are never caught.

Comment: I agree. If you're releasing useful tools and don't expect monetary gain MIT/X11 is the way to go. If you want to waste your life, grow a substantial neck beard, evangelize about computer based religions, and spend your time creating honeypot traps for the evil empires go with GPL. GPL also has the added effect of making other open source developers paranoid about working with your code.

Comment: @Evan: +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: ok i am curious tho what is actually preventing developers to work on GPL code, i dont really bother with the [long definition](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) on what GPL is. but it seems like its "free" software? i like how [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) is so short but i guess thats for designers?

Comment: @jiewmeng If your project uses code released under GPL code, your project must also be released under GPL or a more liberal license. IE, it's free to write code but you're restricted on the licenses you can use. IE, GPL begets GPL. Therefore GPL isn't really free because it restricts your usage. Which is good if you are Richard Stallman and your goal in life is saving your fellow coders in the MIT AI labs from those pesky high paying prestigious jobs in large corporations. GPL is based on politics and "sticking it to the man." Most OS devs don't care about that cause.

Comment: The GPL is a reasonably short "share-and-share-alike" license.  It's easy to comply with.  The complications come when people try to look for loopholes.

Comment: @David: Not true. IANAL, but from my reading of the GPL, it appears that _any_ distribution to _anyone_ in an organization other than your own means you need to comply with the whole of the GPL. I could see this being problematic...

Comment: @Chinmay:  So you provide them with a copy of the license and the source, and everything's OK.  This is incompatible with some business models, but it really was intended to be, and much of the reputation is from people trying to evade it.  If you people to use your code in their own proprietary products, use BSD/MIT/Boost/whatever.  If you want to make sure derivatives of your code are just as free, use the GPL.

Comment: @David: My problem isn't so much that the GPL is cumbersome and viral (though I do have minor problems with it on those counts, but I could just dual-licence to get around those). My problem is with how hard it is to enforce for small projects. As I said in the post, if you're willing to protect your work, the GPL is a reasonable choice. If you don't really care too much, the GPL is a poor choice, even if you get a slight twinge at the thought of commercial entities benefiting from your work.

Comment: *Sigh* [Anybody can sell GPLed software.](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html) This whole thread reads like decade-old FUD. Also, big organizations (I think EFF is one) can help out with legal assistance if you find GPL violations.

Answer (score 3):

Personally your best bet to get a true answer to this question would be to talk with a Legal Professional as they are going to know the specifics.

However, what I remember when i was talking with my lawyer about setting up our code license agreements is that the clause you are talking about basically protects you from cases where you say "this code does X, Y, Z", that is an implied warranty on "fitness for a particular purpose", that clause prevents you have having any issues if it doesn't do X, Y, and Z.

Answer (score 1):

**[WTFPL - Do What The F*** You Want To Public License](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/Blockquote)**

> ```
>        DO WHAT THE F*** YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
>                 Version 2, December 2004
> ```
>
> Copyright (C) 2004 Sam Hocevar
>
> Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim or modified 
>   copies of this license document,
>   and changing it is allowed as long 
>   as the name is changed.
>
> ```
>        DO WHAT THE F*** YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
> TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR COPYING, DISTRIBUTION AND MODIFICATION
> ```
>
> 1. You just DO WHAT THE F*** YOU WANT TO.

Comment: I've never really liked that license. There needs to be a certain amount of control of your own code. There is nothing preventing some commercial company taking your code and making a commercial app out of it?

Comment: @TheLQ: This applies equally to the BSD and MIT/X11 licences, the WTFPL only makes the point more strongly. I don't really like licences that either specifically forbid commercial use or are viral (like the GPL). If I wanted to licence code under the GPL or a non-commercial-only licence, I would _at least_ dual-licence it so that people could buy the right to use the software in a commercial product.

Comment: lol, i saw this b4. but this doesn't protect me from warranty thingy

Answer (score 1):

How are you giving these materials to people?

If you're licensing your application to people commercially, you're going down the wrong path - you need to see a lawyer to prepare a software license agreement. In these situations the customer paying for software licenses get statutory warranties, so clauses like that aren't enforceable.

If you're releasing source code or other materials for others to re-use, your original post is absolutely correct - you MUST include a warranty waiver, otherwise someone might turn around and say "you released this code claiming it did X, Y and Z - but it doesn't and I'm going to sue you", even if you didn't get paid for it.

In either case, you need to sit down and figure out what you want people to be able to do with the product.

In the latter case where you're releasing things to the community under an Open Source license, find a good OSI-approved license that aligns with your wishes:
http://opensource.org/licenses/category

But as greyfade mentions, don't even think about writing your own license - it's not worth the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the BSD license(s)? The simplest (relatively) form of it, known as "Simplified BSD License" or "FreeBSD License", is particularly fit for disclaiming any warranties and/or liabilities. It does not prevent commercialization or use of your code in commercial and/or proprietary software, but it makes sure you still are the copyright holder.

You can read it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_.28.22Simplified_BSD_License.22_or_.22FreeBSD_License.22.29). Depending on the laws of your country, it may be more suitable to your purposes than other, more complicated, licenses.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write a license or select
>   one?

Read over a [list of Free Software licenses](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html) and pick one that makes sense for your aims.

Don't write a license unless you absolutely cannot find one that suits you. If you do write a license, then take grayfade's advice and ask for legal assistance from a solicitor/attorney/whatever.

> I originally thought of creative
>   commons when while reading a book
>   about wordpress

There are a plethora of Creative Commons licenses. Be specific about which one you're thinking of. Some CC licenses are sometimes used for code, but that's not what they were designed for. It's probably best not to use CC licenses for code.

Free Software licenses range from the extremely permissive (WTFPL) to the strongly copyleft (GNU AGPL). Somewhere in that range will be one that suits you.